# How to set an timer in textbox using jquery..?

Tags: jquery, jsp

I have a text box on a jsp page. I want when the page loades the value of textbox should show how much time been the page loaded. Or in simple words i want to setup a countup timer in a textbox which should start immediately and automatically when the page loads. And when the user click on submit button the user navigates to another jsp page shows that how much seconds he took to click the submit button (button was on previous page).

I am doing following HTML

```
<input type="text" id="timeleft" name="timeleft" />
```

In jquery Script i am doing the following :

```
<script type="text/javascript" src="jquery-1.7.2.js"></script>
        <script type="text/javascript">
            $(document).ready(function(){
    var start = new Date;
                    setInterval(function() {
                        $('timeleft').val((new Date - start) / 1000);
                    }, 1000);     });
        </script>
```

But the timer is not visible in textbox...? What is the error..?

Comment: Can someone solve this problem..? thanks.. 
http://stackoverflow.com/questions/11641662/doccookie-is-not-getting-saved-instantly

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Try with this (Based on your code):

```
var start = new Date;
setInterval(timer, 1000);     

function timer() {
        $('#timeleft').val((new Date - start) / 1000);
    }
```

For int: `$('#timeleft').val(parseInt((new Date - start) / 1000))`

Comment: yes this code works but not fully. I am getting the value in decimals. and when i try to use (int) it shows error.

Comment: @Rambo Why not? `$('#timeleft').val(parseInt((new Date - start) / 1000))`

Comment: i used parseInt "val((parseInt(new Date - start) / 1000));" and it works perfectly now. thanks.

Comment: @Rambo OK I'm happy to be useful ;-)

Comment: @ Alex : Hi alex, sorry but the timer is not working properly. I see the count up in the text box but when i navigate to another page i see  the value of of text box 0. Please help again what can b the problem now..?

Comment: @Rambo yes if i correctly understend the problem, this happen because this code work on client, and when you navigate and return on timer page the date is refreshed.

Comment: I got rid of it as well. I made the textbox readonly="readonly" and now i can see the time elapsed on my second page. anyways thanks.

Comment: Hi Alex, Can u solve this problem too.. ?http://stackoverflow.com/questions/11641662/doccookie-is-not-getting-saved-instantly

Answer (score 0):

You need to add the # to your selector.

$('#timeleft') - it is currently looking for a element named timeleft not the ID.

Also new Date will give you this - Wed Jul 18 2012 08:51:56 GMT-0400 (EDT)

if it is a timer you will want to get the time. try this for referance. http://www.w3schools.com/jsref/jsref_gettime.asp

Date Object:
http://www.w3schools.com/jsref/jsref_obj_date.asp

Comment: Yes i did, but yet there is no timer displayed..:(

Comment: that is because you are try to take a String minus a String. you need a number. I updated my answer with a reference for the date. you will have to get each value individually. and do the math accordingly for each.

Comment: No no no, i just want a simple timer which displays that how much seconds elapsed from when the page was loaded.

Comment: yes. but you can't do it the way you are trying. take a look at the date object reference. that should help you.

Date Object: http://www.w3schools.com/jsref/jsref_obj_date.asp

Comment: This should be what you are looking for from what I understand. My apologies for the confusion. 

http://jsfiddle.net/hB7hq/

Answer (score 0):

Just add the # for id selector.

[Demo](http://jsfiddle.net/nsjithin/4p9Wm/1/)

Again if its not displaying in the html, please check there is only one element in your page with id="timeleft"